# Getting HTTP 405 Method not allowed error when calling Web API method from JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, c#-4.0, web

I have the following method in my Web API controller

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetByModule")]
    public Object Get([FromUri]int id)
    {
        //var dblayer = new Db(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]);

        var annDb = new ContactsDB(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]);

        return  annDb.GetContacts(id).Tables[0];
    }
```

Here i the Jquery code  which i am using to call the method

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: link,
        data: null,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {

            alert("Error");

        }
    });
```

The URL which is getting called is

```
http://localhost:56834/api/Contacts/GetByModule?id=9
```

But i keep getting HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed on calling it from Jquery.

Any idea what i may be doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure you are making a "GET" request? (maybe from Fiddler or browser's debug mode). I say this because you seem to setting the "contentType" property in your jquery, which ideally should not be present as you should not be sending body in a "GET" request. Could you share your full raw request(may be from Fiddler)?

Comment: THanks a lot. i removed the content type property and the Web API is now getting called. However i receive the following error - An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage>. I tried serializing the DataTable with JSONConvert but i still receive the error. Any help will be appreciated